# Double linked list in C++ (Pointer memory access violation)

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to implement a double linked list in C++. I get an error which I do not understand. It is a runtime error in `else` branch at line:

`list->tail->next = new_node;`

It says that `list->tail` was at a different memory address. Unfortunately, I have the German version of Visual Studio, so I can not translate it that good. The error is marked as a "write access violation".

Could someone explain me what is going on here?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

typedef struct dlist_node dlist_node;

struct dlist_node {          // represents one node with its data and with pointers to the next and
    dlist_node* next;        // previous node
    dlist_node* prev;
    int data;
};

typedef struct {           // represents nodes of the list that one can access
    dlist_node* head;
    dlist_node* tail;
} dlist;

void dlist_append(dlist* list, int data) {   // to append the list with new data/node
    dlist_node* new_node = new dlist_node;
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = new_node->prev = NULL;
    if (list->tail == NULL) {               // if list is empty
        list->head = list->tail = new_node;
    }
    else {
        list->tail->next = new_node;     // error appears here
        new_node->prev = list->tail;
        list->tail = new_node;
    }
}

int main() {
    dlist* double_linked_list = new dlist;
    std::cout << double_linked_list->head;

    dlist_append(double_linked_list, 42);
    std::cout << double_linked_list->head;
}
```

Comment: `std::cout << double_linked_list->head;` -- Nowhere do you initialize the member variables in `dlist`.  Also `typedef struct` is not necessary in a C++ program -- all you need is `struct dlist { ... };`

Comment: Suggestion: Upgrade your reference materials. You are learning C with `new` and iostreams, not C++.

Comment: If you are required to implement manually with new, then using the `dlist` struct with `head`, `tail` pointers and the `dlist_node` struct is a good approach. But, after initializing `head` and `tail`, don't forget to allocate for and initialize each `dlist_node` node. Essentially you are implementing [Doubly-Linked List of Integers](https://pastebin.com/E6WpPjTC) in C++ with `new` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: Can you give me an example. How do I allocate memory for every dlist_node? I thougt with `dlist_node* new_node = new dlist_node;` I already did that

Comment: See the example link. It is C, but the only difference will be the use of `new` instead of `malloc` The function in the example that adds to the list is `add()` instead of your `dlist_append()`. The `add()` function calls `create_node()` which allocates for an initializes each node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still stuck, then let's see if we can get you unstuck. While C++ already provides doubly linked-list in [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) which should be the preferred list implementation over writing your own. That said, we understand that many of the linked-list self-implementation are exercises for educational purposes, either for self-study or as part of a class. That is fine, you need to fully understand them, there is a lot of legacy-code out there that makes use of all types of self-invented lists.

As noted in the comments, among other issues, your biggest issue is you do not allocate and initialize your `dlist_node` nodes when adding nodes to your list. Your list has two separate `struct`, `dlist` that holds the `head` and `tail` pointers (which with a more encapsulated approach can be made members of the same `struct` or `class` where your `prev` and `next` and payload (data) pointers are declared, and the functions that operate on the list would be member functions)

Using the separate struct is fine, and using both `head` and `tail` pointers within the struct ensures your list additions can be done in-order in O(1) time. While your code has been edited, there is no reason to allocate for `dlist double_linked_list`. You have a struct, you can simply create an instance. The pointers `head` and `tail` will point to a `dlist_node` that you allocate and initialize with each node you add to your list.

The key is that `head` will always point to the first node in your list and `tail` will always point to the last. This provides the starting points for iterating over each node in your list in the forward, and reverse directions. When you add (or append) a node to your list, after setting the `prev` and `next` pointers correctly for each node involved, you simply update the `head` (if inserting a new first node), or `tail` (if adding to the end of the list) pointers accordingly.

When using a simple `int` as the list payload, you can easily allocate for and initialize your new node in your add (append) node function. However, as your payloads become more complicated, it is often convenient to write a `createnode()` function that takes the values needed to fully initialize the node as parameters and then allocates for and fully initializes the node, returning a pointer to the new node on success, or `nullptr` in the case of allocation failure. This allows you to reuse your `add()` function and only customize your `createnode()` for each new list.

Before looking at your add and create node functions, let's look at your structs themselves. While in C, it is convenient to use `typedef` to create an alias for `struct dlist` or `struct dlist_node`, in C++ that is completely unnecessary and often causes more problems than it solves. When you declare a struct in C++, you simply create an instance of the struct and can refer directly to the struct name as a type, e.g.

```
struct dlist_node {                         /* list node */
    int data;
    struct dlist_node *prev, *next;
};

struct dlist {                              /* list wrapper with head & tail pointers */
    dlist_node *head, *tail;
};
```

Now for an `add()` (your `append`) and a `createnode()` function, you could do the following:

```
/** create new node initialize all members */
dlist_node *createnode (int v)
{
    dlist_node *node = new dlist_node;      /* allocate node */
    
    if (!node)                              /* validate allocation (and use try/catch) */
        return nullptr;
    
    node->data = v;                         /* initialize members values */
    node->prev = node->next = nullptr;
    
    return node;    /* return new node */
}

/** add node at end of list, update tail to end */
dlist_node *add (dlist *l, int v)
{
    dlist_node *node = createnode (v);      /* allocate node, initialize data */
    
    if (!node)                              /* validate allocation */
        return nullptr;
    
    if (!l->head)                           /* if 1st node, node is head/tail */
        l->head = l->tail = node;
    else {                                  /* otherwise */
        node->prev = l->tail;               /* set prev to tail */
        l->tail->next = node;               /* add at end, update tail pointer */
        l->tail = node;
    }
    
    return node;    /* return new node */
}
```

Always validate that your allocation has succeeded and handle the error if it fails.

Now to create a list in `main()` (or any other scope where the list is needed) you simply declare an instance of the struct and initialize both `head` and `tail` to `nullptr` (which can be moved to the constructor so it happens automatically), you can do:

```
    dlist list = { nullptr, nullptr };          /* initialize list pointers nullptr */
```

To create a list named `list`. To test the list, add a few nodes to the list, check the list both forward and backwards, and then remove all the nodes in a random order checking all pointers after the removal of each node, e.g.

```
#define NNODES 16
...
    dlist list = { nullptr, nullptr };          /* initialize list pointers nullptr */
    int a[NNODES];                              /* array to shuffle */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < NNODES; i++) {          /* fill array with NNODES int */
        add (&list, i+1);
        a[i] = i+1;
    }
```

(the array is used to hold the node values, so you can shuffle the array and then iterate over the shuffled array removing the nodes in a random order)

You generally will want a function to allow you to delete a specific node, and then all nodes when the list is no longer needed, freeing the memory for a given, or all nodes. You need a function to print the list in forward and reverse directions. If you modify the example I linked to to use `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` and `free` and use `iostream` instead of `stdio.h`, you would have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

#ifndef NNODES
#define NNODES 16
#endif

/*
* non-list misc functions
*/

/** shuffle integer array of size 'n'
*  (using fisher-yates method)
*/
void shuffle (int *a, int n)
{
    std::random_device rd;                        /* random seed */
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());                       /* standard mersenne_twister_engine */
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, NNODES - 1);    /* distribution 0, 15 */
    
    int i, tmp;
    while (n-- > 1) {
        i = dist(gen);
        tmp  = a[i];
        a[i] = a[n];
        a[n] = tmp;
    }
}

/*
* list structs and functions
*/

struct dlist_node {                         /* list node */
    int data;
    struct dlist_node *prev, *next;
};

struct dlist {                              /* list wrapper with head & tail pointers */
    dlist_node *head, *tail;
};

/** create new node initialize all members */
dlist_node *createnode (int v)
{
    dlist_node *node = new dlist_node;      /* allocate node */
    
    if (!node)                              /* validate allocation (and use try/catch) */
        return nullptr;
    
    node->data = v;                         /* initialize members values */
    node->prev = node->next = nullptr;
    
    return node;    /* return new node */
}

/** add node at end of list, update tail to end */
dlist_node *add (dlist *l, int v)
{
    dlist_node *node = createnode (v);      /* allocate node, initialize data */
    
    if (!node)                              /* validate allocation */
        return nullptr;
    
    if (!l->head)                           /* if 1st node, node is head/tail */
        l->head = l->tail = node;
    else {                                  /* otherwise */
        node->prev = l->tail;               /* set prev to tail */
        l->tail->next = node;               /* add at end, update tail pointer */
        l->tail = node;
    }
    
    return node;    /* return new node */
}

/** print all nodes in list */
bool prn (dlist *l)
{
    if (!l->head) {
        std::cout << "list-empty\n";
        return false;
    }
    for (dlist_node *n = l->head; n; n = n->next)
        std::cout << ' ' <<  n->data;
    std::cout.put('\n');
    
    return true;
}

/** print all nodes in list in reverse */
bool prnrev (dlist *l)
{
    if (!l->tail) {
        std::cout << "list-empty\n";
        return true;
    }
    for (dlist_node *n = l->tail; n; n = n->prev)
        std::cout << ' ' <<  n->data;
    std::cout.put('\n');
    
    return false;
}

/** delete node with value v from list (for loop) */
bool del_node (dlist *l, int v)
{
    if (!l->head) {
        std::cout << "list-empty\n";
        return false;
    }
    dlist_node **ppn = &l->head;            /* pointer to pointer */
    dlist_node *pn = l->head;               /* pointer to node */
    
    for (; pn; ppn = &pn->next, pn = pn->next) {
        if (pn->data == v) {
            *ppn = pn->next;                /* set node at address to next */
            
            if (pn != l->tail)              /* prev is next prev */
                (*ppn)->prev = pn->prev;
            else                            /* deleting tail, set tail to prev */
                l->tail = pn->prev;
            
            delete pn;                      /* free current */
            pn = nullptr;
            
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}

/** delete all nodes in list */
void del_nodes (dlist *l)
{
    dlist_node *n = l->head;
    
    while (n) {
        dlist_node *victim = n;
        n = n->next;
        delete victim;
    }
    
    l->head = l->tail = nullptr;
}

int main (void) {
    
    dlist list = { nullptr, nullptr };          /* initialize list pointers nullptr */
    int a[NNODES];                              /* array to shuffle */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < NNODES; i++) {          /* fill array with NNODES int */
        add (&list, i+1);
        a[i] = i+1;
    }
    shuffle (a, NNODES);                        /* shuffle array for random removal */
    
    prn (&list);                                /* print list forward */
    prnrev (&list);                             /* print list reverse */
    std::cout.put('\n');
    
    for (int i = 0; i < NNODES; i++) {          /* remove all nodes in random order */
        std::cout << "deleting : " << a[i] << '\n';
        del_node (&list, a[i]);                 /* delete node with random value a[i] */
        
        if (prn (&list)) {                      /* print list forward if nodes remain */
            prnrev (&list);                     /* print list reverse if nodes remain */
            std::cout.put('\n');                /* tidy up with a '\n' */
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/dlist_dlist_node
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

deleting : 1
 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2

deleting : 9
 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 8 7 6 5 4 3 2

deleting : 12
 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 11 13 14 15 16
 16 15 14 13 11 10 8 7 6 5 4 3 2

deleting : 7
 2 3 4 5 6 8 10 11 13 14 15 16
 16 15 14 13 11 10 8 6 5 4 3 2

deleting : 16
 2 3 4 5 6 8 10 11 13 14 15
 15 14 13 11 10 8 6 5 4 3 2

deleting : 5
 2 3 4 6 8 10 11 13 14 15
 15 14 13 11 10 8 6 4 3 2

deleting : 8
 2 3 4 6 10 11 13 14 15
 15 14 13 11 10 6 4 3 2

deleting : 14
 2 3 4 6 10 11 13 15
 15 13 11 10 6 4 3 2

deleting : 4
 2 3 6 10 11 13 15
 15 13 11 10 6 3 2

deleting : 3
 2 6 10 11 13 15
 15 13 11 10 6 2

deleting : 13
 2 6 10 11 15
 15 11 10 6 2

deleting : 2
 6 10 11 15
 15 11 10 6

deleting : 6
 10 11 15
 15 11 10

deleting : 10
 11 15
 15 11

deleting : 11
 15
 15

deleting : 15
list-empty
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/dlist_dlist_node
==17580== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17580== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17580== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17580== Command: ./bin/dlist_dlist_node
==17580==
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

deleting : 15
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 16
 16 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
...
deleting : 16
 12
 12

deleting : 12
list-empty
==17580==
==17580== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17580==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17580==   total heap usage: 19 allocs, 19 frees, 74,664 bytes allocated
==17580==
==17580== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==17580==
==17580== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17580== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.